# Printing a formatted document with sql data without using windows forms

Tags: c#, printing

Currently we're making a c# application (using WPF) and everything goes well. The only problem we have right now is that we want our application to be able to print documents directly from our application to the printer.

What we need to print is a list of customers, but not listed on a sheet, instead it should print 1 full page of information from every customer that yet haven't been printed. The document should also contain some formatting such as a "Result" section where you manually fill in information using a pen later on.

I've found several solutions but they all require us to either use iTextSharp and have Acrobat Reader installed. This way works but just complicated things for later on as some of our teachers doesn't even know what google chrome is, and less so even grasp the concept of having to install acrobat reader to be able to run this program.

Our other option is to create a simple report directly in c#, but all the tutorials use windows forms and a datagrid which doesn't feel very effective for what we're trying to achieve. Also we can't find reports in the "add new" menu for the solution explorer and we're not using windows forms.

Basically we want to press a button which automatically prints all the new customers that yet haven't been printed out. We're all good with the other backend stuff like marking the customer to not be printed again and so on, it's just the actual document formatting that've had us stuck for days now. I've searched for "c# create invoice" and so on, but every tutorial uses windows forms or Crystal Reports while we can't.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Printing.PrintDocument) ?

Comment: I've found and read that class, but the thing is that reading that alone can't help me create a working function that formats it the way I want to. I'm not even a native English speaker and those sites are just way to much to grasp. Like reading a complicated equation without knowing the basics. I mean we know what the stuff says, but it's so much stuff and it would take us days to get what we want only using that tutorial.